# How do I export this mesh to a obj?

Tags: mesh, objects, export

I'd want to export this mesh to an OBJ and open it in Spark Ar but in Spark it only opens the faceMesh layer 
[image: This is the mesh]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Spark Ar, but maybe this can help you out: https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/3nfr7c/export_only_vertices/